# DocuSign API - define from which group (in case an user is linked to multiple groups) the envelope must be sent

Tags: docusignapi, group, envelope

We use API connection to send envelopes. I found how to apply brand in the envelope but not group. Can I set the group (and associated parameters) in the envelope, as some of my users are identified in several groups?

Thank you

We send and receive envelopes using only one account now, but we need to configure more accounts to deal with different settings

Answer (score 0):

First, not sure if when you say "group" you mean account, or you mean group, because both things exist in DocuSign, and are different.

Second, since this is Stackoverflow, I'll assume you are writing code and building an integration and not just using the web app.

So, I'll address both options:

**Group:**

[This article](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/common-api-tasks-requesting-signature-signing-group) shows you how to do this in 6 langs, here is how the C# code looks like:

```
// signingGroupId should hold the string with the Signing Group ID
Signer signer1 = new Signer 
{
    Name = "test1", // Signing group name
    SigningGroupId = signingGroupId,
    RecipientId = "1",
};
```

Note that you have to have a group and find the ID for this group.

**Account:**

If you are using the API, the account is based on the authentication or on the access token you obtained. You will have to use a different account to authenticate and also make API calls.
`AccountId` is a unique GUID that determines the account you use and is passed on the URL for each API, however, it's not enough just to change this URL, you have to have an access token obtained for this account by using either [JWT](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/) or

[Auth Code Grant](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/authcode/)

.

Comment: Thank you @inbar Gazit for your answers. You are correct I'm building an integration. For the group, it's not signing group, it's group you can create and configure under one account (as Administrator) "In eSignature, groups can be used to control access to templates and branding" , "dministrators use groups to organize users into functional units for template sharing and other functions"

Comment: These are permissions groups and have nothing to do with envelopes you sent. So the question doesn't make sense if that's the groups you mean.